# Can I have multiple "farms" under a single tenant on SharePoint Online / Office 365?

Tags: tenant

Migrating to Office 365 soon and wanted to know if I could have multiple SharePoint 'Farms' under one Tenant? We have 3 business units we want to keep separated, but allow smooth User experience if a User needs to hop around to different 'farms'.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to provision multiple tenants and there is functionality that doesn't work for Guests in SPO.

I would look at Conditional Access Policies in Azure if you want to limit access to specific sites, etc.